# Change first character and fill down

Tags: windows

I have over 500 rows that are numbered 1-HP-L34904-FW and so on. They all have a 1 as the first character, I want to change all of the 1's to a 2, all the way down?

Comment: You mean with Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
="2"&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

Change A1 to your Column and drag it down
The Formula:

- Concatenate 2 with the rest
- the rest is thr Right part of the Data without the first 1
- Len(A1) -1 give the number of character -1 to the Right Formula to leave the first 1